# Duplicate value has been Inserted without my knowledge

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have developed one web application by PHP & MySQL. I got an issue part of room allocation module.

In Room Allocation module, User can choose multiple check box (Time slot) depends on their need. In back end, I Collect those time and save into database.

Some times, same data inserted into database twice. It's only occurred some times. Mostly I got proper Output.

My Questions are :

1. **Why It's happening only in some times?**
2. **Where duplicate value created?**
3. **how it happen?**
4. **How to rectify this problem!!**

Please some one help me to avoid this problem.!!!

My Insert Coding:

```
    $admin = $_POST['admin'];

    $roomno = $_POST['str_roomno']; //unique No
    $currentdate = $_POST['str_currentDate'];
    $employeeID = $_POST['str_empID']; //current user ID

    $list_id = $_POST['list'];     //collect list of time slot from previous page
    $total_checkedRows   = count($list_id);   //counting the total slot from previous page



    for($i = 0; $i < $total_checkedRows; $i++)
        {
            $fromTime =  $_POST['time_fromTime'.$list_id[$i]];
            $endTime =  $_POST['time_endTime'.$list_id[$i]];
            $status  = $_POST['str_status'.$list_id[$i]];
            $reason =  $_POST['str_comment'] ; 
            $statusCheck = "occupied";

            if(isset($_POST['id_bookedID'.$list_id[$i]])){
                $id_lineID = $_POST['id_bookedID'.$list_id[$i]];
            }

            if($status == 1)
            {
            $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO hrms_room_calendar (room_id, booking_date, from_time, to_time, employee_id , booking_status, reason) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                                   GetSQLValueString($roomno, "int"),
                                   GetSQLValueString($currentdate, "date"),
                                   GetSQLValueString($fromTime, "text"),
                                   GetSQLValueString($endTime, "text"),
                                   GetSQLValueString($employeeID, "int"),
                                   GetSQLValueString($statusCheck, "text"),
                                   GetSQLValueString($reason, "text"));

              $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL) or die(mysql_error());
            } 
            else if ($status == 2)
            {
                $updateQuery = sprintf("update hrms_room_calendar set booking_status = %s , employee_id = %s, reason = %s where booking_id = %s",
                                   GetSQLValueString($statusCheck, "text"),
                                   GetSQLValueString($employeeID, "int"),
                                   GetSQLValueString($reason , "text"),
                                   GetSQLValueString($id_lineID, "int"));
                $Result1 = mysql_query($updateQuery) or die(mysql_error());
            }
```

Check Box Coding:

```
 <form action="BookOrCancel_room.php" method="POST" name="from_roomdetailsfillter" id="from_roomdetailsfillter" onsubmit="return mycommendfunction(1);" >
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['roomid'] ; ?>" name="str_roomno" />
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['calender'] ; ?>" name="str_currentDate" />
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $LoginEmpID ; ?>" name="str_empID" />
<input type="hidden"  name="str_comment" id="id_commend" /> <!--value coming from js -->
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $admin; ?>" name="admin" />

<?php

foreach($range as $timeRange)  
{ 
        $count ++;
        $fromTime = $timeRange;

        $add_time=strtotime($fromTime)+60;
        $fromTime = date("h:i A", $add_time); //Now starting time + 1 Min


        $Endtime_in_db_24_hour_format = $dbendTime; //Detractly retireve from database

        echo "<input type='text' name='time_fromTime$count' value='$Fromtime_in_24_hour_format' style = 'display: none;'/>
        <input type='text' name='time_endTime$count' value='$Endtime_in_24_hour_format' style = 'display: none;'/> ";

        $link = "BookOrCancel_room.php?roomno=".$roomid."&Currentdate=". $date_Entered. "&employeeID=" . $LoginEmpID . "&fromTime=". $Fromtime_in_24_hour_format."&endTime=".$Endtime_in_24_hour_format;

        if($total_roomdetails > 0)
        { //check initially whether current date atleast once present in database

        //check room already booked or not
        $query_EmpName = sprintf("SELECT * FROM hrms_room_calendar WHERE booking_date = %s and room_id = %s", GetSQLValueString($date_Entered, "date"), GetSQLValueString($roomid, "int"));
        $roomdetails = mysql_query($query_EmpName) or die(mysql_error());

        while($retriveBookedStatus = mysql_fetch_array($roomdetails))
        {

            $db_from_time =  strtotime($retriveBookedStatus['from_time']);
            $local_from_time = strtotime($fromTime);

            if($db_from_time == $local_from_time) 
            {

                $cancelLink = $link."&id=".$retriveBookedStatus['booking_id']."&admin=".$admin;
                echo  "<input type='hidden' name='id_bookedID$count' value=" . $retriveBookedStatus['booking_id']. ">";

                $str_reason = $retriveBookedStatus['reason'];
                $str_cancel_reason = $retriveBookedStatus['cancelled_remarks'];

                   //Display Reason {.............}

                  //Display Employee Name  {.............}

                    if(($status == 2) and ($total_accessdetails_Recordset > 0) and ($date_exited == 0))
                    { //canceled it can book by others
                        $status = 0;
                        //echo "<td style = 'display: none;'><a href=".$cancelLink."&status=2" . " onclick='return confirmCancel();'><input type='button' name='Booked' value='Book'></a></td>";

                        echo "<input type='hidden' value=2 name='str_status$count' />";

                        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='list[]' value=$count  id='checkboxbook'  /> <td>";


                    }

            } //if($db_from_time == $local_from_time) 
         }//while

        if($flag != 1) 
        { 
            $flag = 0;

            echo "<tr  height='25' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
            <td>";
            echo $fromTime . " - ".$endTime ;
            //Check Whether ending time exited dbEnd Time
            echo TimeExited($Endtime_in_24_hour_format, $Endtime_in_db_24_hour_format );

            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td title='Free'> Available </td>";
            echo "<td align='center'> - </td>";
            echo "<td align='center'> - </td>";
            if(($total_accessdetails_Recordset > 0) and ($date_exited == 0)){ 
            //That particular time and date didnt present in db that is also should not booked
                echo "<td style = 'display: none;'><a href=".$link."&status=1" . " target='_blank'><input type='button' name='Booked' value='Book'></a></td>";
                echo "<input type='hidden' value=1 name='str_status$count' />";

                    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='list[]' value=$count id='checkboxbook'  disabled/> <td>";


            } //    if($total_accessdetails_Recordset > 0) 
        } //if($flag != 1)
        else 
        {
            $flag = 0;
        }

    } // if($total_roomdetails > 0)
    else 
    { 

        echo "<tr  height='25' bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
        <td>";
        echo $fromTime . " - ".$endTime ;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td title='Free'>Available </td>";
        echo "<td align='center'> - </td>";
        echo "<td align='center'> - </td>";
        if(($total_accessdetails_Recordset > 0) and ($date_exited == 0)){ //while loading time slot should not booked
            echo "<td style = 'display: none;'><a href=".$link."&status=1" . " target='_blank'><input type='button' name='Booked' value='Book' ></a></td>";
                echo "<input type='hidden' value=1 name='str_status$count' />";

                            echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='list[]' value=$count id='checkboxbook'  /> <td>";

    }//($total_accessdetails_Recordset > 0)
 } //else
echo "</tr>";
} // foreach
  ?>
   </form>
```

[image: My Error. It's Only happened some times]

Comment: Please show your check box list.

Comment: HI shweta, Whether screenshot or coding? check box!

Comment: you can show coding part.

Comment: And also print $_POST variables at php side so that you can understand from which side the duplicate values are generated.

Comment: Check ID's of duplicated rows. It's possible, that they're not really duplicated in your database but that some rows are selected multiple times because of some badly designed `JOIN`. If ID of these rows is the same, then you have problem with `JOIN` and if not, then you have problem in processing `POST` requests.

Comment: hi shwetha, I have gave check box coding. Kindly check it.

Comment: may be same values are inserted many times but each time id is unique so data is getting inserted

Comment: Hi Grzegorz, Yep, My id in db is different. In your point of you, My post method is wrong. Can you help me to find out mistake, where I did!